# ASP NET 5 - Custom Authentication scheme handler is ignored when using Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

Custom authentication scheme and handlers are ignored.
When controller method is annotated by `[Authorize]`, my scheme is not challenged even though it is set as default authentication scheme. Instead, 302 status is send with redirection to `/Accounts/Login...`.
Not only that this URL does not even exist in my app (I am using Blazor WASM on client side), but there is no code at all in my application that should inflict this behavior.
My authentication handler is invoked when I specify it directly in the attribute: `[Authorize(AuthenticationScheme = CustomAuthHandler.SchemeName)]`

Why is default authentication scheme ignored and instead is run something not specified in the code at all?
If `AddIdentity()` configures this unexpected behavior, where is it documented and how can it be reconfigured?
How to make the framework not ignore my handler, registered as default?

Everything worked properly until i switched to .NET 5 and started using Identity framework.

This is my `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        {
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ServerVersion.FromString("10.5.6-mariadb"));
        });

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(
        options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
            }    
        )
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUserClaimsFactory>();

services.AddControllersWithViews();
services.AddRazorPages();

services.AddAuthentication(
     options =>
     {
         options.DefaultScheme = CustomAuthHandler.SchemeName;
     }
)
.AddScheme<AuthenticationSchemeOptions, CustomAuthHandler>(CustomAuthHandler.SchemeName, x => {  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, `AddIdentity()` method actually caused the problem.
Solution is to replace it with `AddIdentityCore()`, which is more lightweight method and does less under the hood. Then the missing services have to be added manually, e.g. `AddRoles()`, as stated in documentation.